# vb6 common dialog box save as, which file extension was chosen

Tags: vb6

With the common dialog control, lets say I set

```
.Filter = "Text (.txt)|*.txt|Comma Separated (.csv)|*.csv|Excel (.xls)|*.xls"
```

If the user does not explicitly type `.txt` or `.csv` or `.xls` but just enters a filename, how does one know **WHICH** extension they want it saved as?

Comment: `.Filter` has it in it on return. *nFilterIndex 
Specifies the index of the currently selected filter in the File Types control. The buffer pointed to by lpstrFilter contains pairs of strings that define the filters. The first pair of strings has an index value of 1, the second pair 2, and so on. An index of zero indicates the custom filter specified by lpstrCustomFilter. You can specify an index on input to indicate the initial filter description and filter pattern for the dialog box*. **When the user selects a file, nFilterIndex returns the index of the currently displayed filter.**

Comment: @ACatInLove - This should be an answer, not a comment. It's right and it solves the OP's issue.

Comment: nFilterIndex does NOT Specify the index of the currently selected filter

Comment: FilterIndex Property

Returns or sets a default filter for an Open or Save As dialog box.

err!  wrong answer Bahman   DEFAULT  not selected  DEFAULT

Comment: Reading MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238825(v=vs.60).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238813(v=vs.60).aspx)) It is not totally clear what it is supposed to do. It sounds like perhaps it is meant to be used ONLY for setting the default (not for reading the user's selection). But nonetheless reading the selection from it DOES WORK and we have code which relies on this.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. No matter which filetype selection was made it always returns 0

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, `FilterIndex` can unfortunately only be used to specify the default filter, and the Common Dialog Control will not actually give you the filter selected by the user.

I too had to do the same and switch to the Win32 API version.  Here's a well written example and goes into great detail about the use of the `GetSaveFileName()` API and `OPENFILENAME` structure:

http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/g/getsavefilename.html

At which point, you can use the `filebox.nFilterIndex` parameter after the `GetSaveFileName()` call to see what the user had actually selected.